# Why use Entity Framework's DbEntity?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

When I generate a project based on the VS2012 Single-Page MVC Web Application, the base project includes lots of references to DbEntity.

Why:

```
db.Entry(todoList).Entity.UserId
```

rather than just:

```
todoList.UserId
```

It uses this indirection repeatedly in the sample ApiControllers, but only once calls a DbEntityEntry-specific member (the State property). Is there some important reason for using this that I'm overlooking?

EDIT: Here is a larger snippet

```
// DELETE api/TodoList/5
[ValidateHttpAntiForgeryToken]
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteTodoList(int id) {
    TodoList todoList = db.TodoLists.Find(id);
    if (todoList == null) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    if (db.Entry(todoList).Entity.UserId != User.Identity.Name) {
        // Trying to delete a record that does not belong to the user
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
```

Comment: Seems like newbieish redundancy or a pattern someone paranoid about detached entities would adopt pervasively.

Comment: Thanks millimoose. Yeah, a detached entity makes a little more sense. Can't happen in this sample, but I can see how that would be more likely to sneak up on me than an unpersisted entity, if I were busily cranking out controller actions that materialize raw entities rather than DTOs or ViewModels. :) (read as: "I can see where that would be an issue if I were a slacker anyway")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's there to let you make sure that you're referencing the *database entity*, not just an instance (of that model class) that may have no presence in the database.

Comment: Seeing as the object is retrieved through `db.TodoLists.Find()`, it seems pointless.

Comment: Is that then just some programmer practicing semantic prophylactic when building the sample? It seems to me that since the db context in the sample is on the instance, even the Find(id) won't have a chance of returning anything from memory.

Comment: Yeah, Find() can return an unpersisted entity, but even if it could (suppose I modified the scope of DbContext from the sample), then I would want it deleted, in this code sample.

Comment: @millimoose The scaffolding mechanism generates correct code already so, naturally, the model instance returned by `Find()` would be the one in the `DbSet` anyway, yes. But that code could be modified by the user (don't forget that this generated action is merely a starting point and is encouraged to be changed according to the application's needs). Therefore, demonstrating that possibility isn't completely pointless.

Comment: Thank you guys. The discussion has given me a foothold on why I would/wouldn't need it.